# How to prevent a OAuth attack (see attack scenario)?

Tags: security, authentication, web, oauth, oauth-2.0

Here is the attack scenario of how an attacker can takeover victim's account:

1. Attacker is authenticated at provider.com
2. Attacker initiates a process of authenticating with provider.com at some site.com
3. Attacker doesn't exchange an auth code for an access token and copies the link `https://provider.com/oauth/authenticate?code={authorization-code}`which is then sent to a victim
4. The victim is authenticated on provider and clicks the above link, exchanges an auth code for an access token and ends up being authenticated on site.com with the victim's account
5. Attacker now continues the authorization process and exchanges the same auth code for an access token and ends up being authenticated on site.com with the **victim's** account.

How to prevent this kind of attacks that exploit a weakness in the OAuth protocol?
Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If a [state](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-state) parameter was maintained by site.com then the attacker's state code would be bound to his/her browser but not the victim's. Therefore site.com would not be able to correlate the state code with the victim's browser session when he/she clicks on the malicious URL.

Have a look at what the [Oauth2.0 spec says](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-30#section-10.12) about this.